# add DatiTime to DateTime, doctrine 2 not see changes

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have some action where need update DateTime property. I wrote

```
public function foo()
{
     $this->completionTime = $this->completionTime->add(new \DateInterval('P1W'));
}
```

property `completionTime` **successful updated** in object, but doctrine don't see changes and don't save this.

When I update some other property, doctrine save this property, but completionTime not save again.
Also I write $this->compleationTime = new \DateTime('now') property updated and saved normal.

Any ideas?

Now I have this code, it's work, but...

```
$time = $this->completionTime->getTimestamp() + 3600 * 24 * 7;
$this->completionTime = new \DateTime(date(DATE_ATOM, $time), new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Kiev'));
```

Comment: what's the mapping you have for `completionTime`?

Comment: @jere I don't understend you.

Answer (score 4):

In doctrine2 documentation, dates are detected by reference ([source](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html#datetime-changes-are-detected-by-reference)).

```
$this->completionTime = clone $this->completionTime;
$this->completionTime->add(...)
```

The above snippet should work.